# Proof of funds for visiting visa

Tags: visas, canada, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

Am applying for visiting visa to Canada with my wife and three kids, what is the range of funds require to be in my statement of account?

Answer (score 1):

First, please take a look at one of our guides on what bank statements say about you:

- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

There is no fix amount required, but your funds must demonstrate several things:

## Enough funds for your stay

You have enough funds to support yourself and your family while you are there without working illegally. Your funds also have a consistent amount. You also have assess which will cover the expense of your trip.

## You have something to return to

The immigration officer also needs convincing that you will go back to your home country and you won’t stay and live there.

See https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/proof-funds-financial-support.html

Comment: While the guidance you’ve given is relevant, OP wants to visit Canada, not the U.K.?

Comment: It's important to make a special note regarding that Canadian web site advice: It is how visa officers will evaluate the visa application. When it says "You" it refers to the visa officer.